# How to always push initial screen to stack navigator (react-navigation@5)

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I'm building a React Native app using react-navigation (version 5) library to implement navigation.

I have a tab navigator that contains a stack navigator on each tab. Each stack navigator has a "landing page", i.e. the `initialRouteName` that is shown when tab is activated.

Let's say the structure is:

```
Tabs
|
+-- Stack1
|     |
|     +-- Stack1LandingPage
|     |
|     +-- Stack1ContentPage
|
+-- Stack2
      |
      +-- Stack2LandingPage
      |
      +-- Stack2ContentPage
```

Problem is, when I try navigate directly from `Stack1LandingPage` to `Stack2ContentPage`, the `Stack2` stack is as follows:

```
Stack2ContentPage
```

and thus there's no "back" button on header to go back to `Stack2LandingPage`.

What I'd like to have instead is to **always** have the landing page on bottom of each stack. So, when I navigate  from `Stack1LandingPage` to `Stack2ContentPage`, the `Stack2` stack would be as follows:

```
Stack2ContentPage
Stack2LandingPage
```

How could this be implemented with react-navigation version 5?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you need to render the initial route specified in the navigator, you can disable the behaviour of using the specified screen as the initial screen by setting initial: false:

```
navigation.navigate('Root', {
  screen: 'Settings',
  initial: false,
});
```

ref: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/nesting-navigators/#rendering-initial-route-defined-in-the-navigator

Comment: Thank you! That made the trick ❤️  I had already implemented a horrible hack to overcome this (reset the whole root state :)

Comment: Is there a way to make this behaviour the default? Because it not being the default is kind of counter intuitive.

Comment: I haven't tried... but maybe this could be helpful?

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/custom-navigators

Comment: @SyedSaeedulHassanAli how would you handle this with an external deeplink opening your app like `myapp://root/settings` here you can't pass that initial prop.. find this also counter intuitive you explicitly need to set this on navigation. Any clue? :)

Comment: Worked like a charm. ChatGPT was no help, suggested all sort of weird solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to clear the stack of the navigation before navigating, so when you return to that navigation, the navigation starts from the top

```
      navigation.dispatch(StackActions.popToTop());
      navigation.navigate("NextScreen");
```